# Can't properly load typescript class into react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, loader

I am currently facing the issue, that I can't assign any default value to a Typescript Class in my React Project (Docusaurus).

Works

```
class Test {
  private hello: string;
  constructor() {
    this.hello = "hi";
  }
}
```

Doesn't work and drops issue below

```
class Test {
  private hello = "hi";
  constructor() {}
}
```

```
/*
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export class AutoTyper{test="hello";constructor(){}}
 @ ./.docusaurus/registry.js 1:5122-5244 1:4769-5019
 @ ./node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/client/exports/ComponentCreator.js
 @ ./.docusaurus/routes.js
 @ ./node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/client/clientEntry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/client/clientEntry.js
 */
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src/"]
}
```

@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Docusaurus v2",
  "docs": "https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/typescript-support",
  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["DOM"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": ["node", "@docusaurus/module-type-aliases"]
  }
}
```

Easy to reproduce by cloning the project and starting it in the 'newdesign' branch.
https://github.com/agile-ts/documentation/tree/newdessign

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see they use require instead of import in their docs, perhaps try that?
const React = require('react');

```
const CompLibrary = require('../../core/CompLibrary.js');

const Container = CompLibrary.Container;
const GridBlock = CompLibrary.GridBlock;

function HelloWorld(props) {
  return (
    <div className="docMainWrapper wrapper">
      <Container className="mainContainer documentContainer postContainer">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is my first page!</p>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

Comment: I haven't imported the plain ts class anywhere yet.. 
and it shouldn't be a react class, it just should be a plain ts class to handle some logic..